# Is it possible to display rokuyo in the Windows 10 taskbar calendar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, calendar

The *[rokuyo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_calendar#Rokuy%C5%8D)* in traditional Japanese calendar dictates how lucky a given day is.

For anyone curious, *rokuyo* is **completely different** from "[solar terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_term)", otherwise known as *sekki* in Japanese or *jieqi* in Chinese.

On Windows 10, in the Calendar *App* (not the taskbar calendar), I can display *rokuyo*, like so:

[image: Notice the two logograms by each day]

In the *taskbar* calendar, however, I can only show the Chinese Lunar calendar, like so:

[image: No rokuyo here!]

Short of switching to the Calendar App, which is slow to open and laggy in general, is there a way to display *rokuyo* in the taskbar calendar?

I have tried switching the "Format" in "Change date, time, or number formats" to "Japanese". The only thing that changes visibly in the taskbar calendar is that the names of the days of the week are changed to their Japanese equivalents.

Comment: For anyone curious, _rokuyo_ is **completely different** from "solar terms" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_term), otherwise known as _sekki_ in Japanese or _jieqi_ in Chinese.

Comment: That information should be contained in your question not a comment

Comment: The Windows taskbar outside of a few tweaks to its look has really remained unchanged. To put it simply it isn’t a full featured calendar